# find function make the expression satisfy certain properties

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

If a function $k(x)$ satisfy the follows expression

$$ a k^2 + b k \dot{k} + c = h$$

Here $a,b,c$ is constant, and $h$ is the function of $x$ and the image is greater than $0$ in domain $x\in \mathbb{R} $.

How to find $k(x)$?

Is there any analytical method in functional analysis that can solve this kind of problem, and are there any relevant examples?

Any advice and reference well be much appreciate!

I thought about it for a while, if given specific $a,b,c,h$ as follows,

$$ k^2 + Cos(x) k \dot{k} + 0 = x^2  + 1$$

we can transform it to solve differential equation. The problem becomes how to find a general solution to this type of equation.

Comment: @user84999 thank you, maybe it is simpler to think h as a constant first, my final goal is that $h$ is a function of x, and the image of $h$ is greater than $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First divide by $b$, and relabel: $\alpha=a/b$, $\eta(x)=h(x)/b$, $\gamma=c/b$. Your equation is then equivalent to

$$
\alpha k^2 +k\dot{k}=\eta(x)-\gamma
$$

Which, using $\eta(x)-\gamma=g(x)$, is equivalent to

$$
\alpha k^2+k\dot{k}=g(x)
$$

The LHS may be written as a total derivative by multiplying the whole equation by the integrating factor $e^{2\alpha x}$, so that

$$
\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dx}\left(e^{2\alpha x}k^2 \right)=e^{2\alpha x}\left(\alpha k^2+k\dot{k} \right)=e^{2\alpha x}g(x)
$$

Integrating, we have

$$
e^{2\alpha x}k^2=2\int\limits^x dx'e^{2\alpha x'}g(x')+C
$$

Where $C$ is the integration constant to be determined by the initial condition. Solving for $k(x)$ we find

$$
k(x)=\pm\left[e^{-2\alpha x}\left(2\int\limits^x dx'e^{2\alpha x'}g(x')+C \right) \right]^{1/2}
$$